# Running One off GCM Network Manager task on Push

Tags: android, performance, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

In an Android app, I perform a data poll from server on push. When the device receives a push it pings the server to get the latest data.

As the user base grows, Server could potentially get 1000's of request at the time of push taking the backend down. I am looking for a good alternative so that I can spread out the server call in a given time window say next 2 hours. What is the a good way to do it?

I was looking into [GCM Network Manager](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager) One-off task. One thing I am not certain is that even if I set a time-window start now with offset of 2 hours, since the device would be connected to the network when the push is received, it would trigger the server call right away defeating the purpose. 
Any suggestions on what might be a good way to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the task will execute immediately, as the GCM network manager doesn't execute only when the network is up, but tries to batch jobs together to reduce the number of wakeups and power consumption.

However, to be safe, when you create the OneoffTask, you can set an [execution window](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/OneoffTask.Builder.html#setExecutionWindow(long,%20long)). There you can set a minimum amount of time before the task will run. I suggest using a random number of seconds, e.g. between 0 and 60 to reduce the potential load on your server.